# Regex in intent-filter of Android Manifest

Tags: android, regex, android-manifest, intentfilter, deep-linking

I am trying to include a regex in order to implement deeplinking to my activity. We have to activities that share a similar schema which is as follows:

Activity A - http://www.google.com/a/process?abc=xyz
Activity B - http://www.google.com/a//?pqr=efg.

Now I declared the deeplink in the manifest as follows :

```
<activity 
             android:name="com.xyz.samples.ActiivtyB" >
             <intent-filter android:label="SimpleB">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="www.google.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/a/"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The above declaration for Activity B resolves both urls (mentioned above) since they share the same path till '/a/'. 
However this is not the problem with Activity A, since its manifest is declared as below :

```
<activity 
                 android:name="com.xyz.samples.ActiivtyA" >
                 <intent-filter android:label="SimpleA">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="www.google.com"
                        android:pathPrefix="/a/process"
                        android:scheme="http" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Hence I came thought of using "regex" which identifies urls of type **/a/**, I verified the regex [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) and it is working. Even I wrote a simple Java program to verify this and it is working fine. The regex is **/a/)(?!\bsuccess\b).***

When I tried to create the deeplink with the above regex, app is not able to resolve the URL of type http://www.google.com/a//?pqr=efg. The manifest is updated as follows :

```
<activity 
                 android:name="com.xyz.samples.ActiivtyB" >
                 <intent-filter android:label="SimpleB">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="www.google.com"
                        android:pathPattern="(/a/)(?!\\bsuccess\\b).\\*"
                        android:scheme="http" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Any help or insights on how to declare regex in manifest will be really helpful. 
I gone thru the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) and updated the regex accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You mis-escaped your pattern - `.\\*` matches the literal string `.*`. But also:

`pathPattern` isn't a real regex, but a [weird subset of regex](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher.html#PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB). I don't think there's a way to exclude /a/success with those options.

Comment: Mike, so do see any alternative for this ?